# NSButton - Gray rectangle whenever the custom button is clicked

Tags: xcode, macos, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

Can I just want to replace the appearance by setting a property of NSButton?

I am able to change the appearance by using the "image" property of the button but I got an ugly gray rectangle whenever the custom button is clicked (the image has a transparency). Is there a way to hide that rectangle?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the button type to UIButtonTypeCustom? As this is tagged with iOS I am going to assume you are speaking of UIButton.

Comment: Ah wrong tag sorry. I am developing mac application. I'll fix tag now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following call changes the behavior by making image be darkened when clicked:

```
[[button cell] setHighlightsBy:NSContentsCellMask];
```